# Cannot understand output of following Java Program

Tags: java, output

I am new to Java and has doubt regarding the output for this code

```
public class Employee{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<String> stationeryList;

    public Employee(String name, int age, List<String> stationeryList)
    {
      this.name= name;
      this.age = age;
      this.stationeryList = stationeryList;
    }

    // getter methods
    public String getName()
    {
       return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
      return age;
    }

    public List<String> getStationeryList()
    {
        return stationeryList;
    }    

    }

    public static void main(){
    String name = "XYZ";
    int age = 34;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Chair");
    Employee emp = new Employee(name, age, list);
    list.add("Desk");
    for(String str:emp.getStationeryList())
     System.out.println(str);
    }
```

This prints both Chair and Desk while I was expecting it to print only Chair since when we created the emp object list had only Chair. Can someone explain the reason behind this.

Comment: @yashpandey Actually, Java is pass by value, but the value passed is the reference to the list.

Comment: @yashpandey Java is not pass by reference, and that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @shmosel yeah, well I was wrong, thanks, I clarified, its pass reference by value.

Comment: @ModusTollens, So in this case, emp.getStationerList, is a reference to actual list and hence when he is looping through it, the output is the actual content that is chair and desk, and not what he passed, its just a reference.

Comment: @yashpandey Yes, that is correct. The value passed is the reference to the one existing list.

Comment: @ModusTollens So the OP gets his answer. :)

Comment: @yashpandey yes, please post this as the answer if you like!

Comment: @ModusTollens Nahh, he can understand through comment section, so that will be fine !! Thanks for clarifying my doubts also. :)

Comment: @user6181208 , you can get the answer from comment section

Comment: Can someone also describe the memory model here. Since list in main method should be on stack as its local variable and emp object should be on heap so how heap object is getting updated by updating a local variable on stack ?

Comment: Object employee has a reference to list of main method, its not copying list from stack to heap, its taking reference to the list in stack into object of Employee in heap.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding after creating List object....So it will store in List memory ...
 use    `list.index(0);`     to print only Chair

Answer (score 0):

Firstly We need to understand what is reference variable here :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

here **list** reference variable has reference of **ArrayList** object so it means it list always have memory address of ArrayList object.

Whenever you will add a new element its always referring the same address of **ArrayList** object .

You are adding **Desk** into **list** object so its referring same memory address.

That is the reason its retaining the values of object that we passed as reference here

```
 Employee emp = new Employee(name, age, list);
```

so in conclusion its same object both the time thats reason its printing both.